# Unable to display the data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

This is my code:

```
if(data.error) {
        msg1.textContent=data.error
}
else {
        msg1.textContent=data.location
        msg2.textContent=data.forecast
        console.log(data.forecast)            
}
})
```

However, I'm not getting output for `msg2`. It displays `[object Object]`. But the same when used with `console.log(data.forecast)` displays the below:

[image]

How can I display the values in `data[0]` ie. partly cloudy

Comment: I feel like there is some code missing... ?

Comment: post the whole code pls. this is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since data is logging an object with property called data. You can get the value like this: `data.forecast.data[0]` if you want display all the values inside data array you can use join method in order to display values seperated by comma like this: `data.forecast.data.join(", ")`